# Error converting date with two digits for the Year field

Tags: java, date, date-conversion, date-parsing, 2-digit-year

```
// input format: dd/MM/yy
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
// output format: yyyy-MM-dd
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse("12/1/20"))); // 0020-11-01
```

I am using the above code but it is giving me year as '0020' instead of '2020'.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to immediately stop using old calendar classes like `Date`, `Calendar` or `SimpleDateFormat`. Instead, start using the newer Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get `2020-01-12`. I believe it’s exactly what you want? What might I be doing differently from the way you are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.time` for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "12/1/20";
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/M/yy"));
    System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

The output is

```
2020-01-12
```

Pay attention to the amount of `M` in the patterns, you cannot parse a `String` that contains a single digit for a month using a double `M` here.

Comment: Good answer. Possible variant depending on taste: `localDate.toString()`.

Answer (score -1):

Most Java devs would be tempted to answer [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but it's not thread safe.

So I recommend you use Java 8 DateFormat.

Assuming your current Date is a **String**:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") ;

String dateString ="20/4/20";

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);
```

If you are using less than Java 8 use [joda time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for the same classes. 
Once you have converted it as a date object use required format and use LocalDate.

```
format(date, new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")) ;
```

Comment: That's irrelevant, since the only thing I modified was the title and a tag. It would have been wrong anyway. You shouldn't respond to the title, but to the title *and* the body.

Comment: It doesn't make sence to suggest solutions for java versions less than java 8

Comment: You never know who may still be using a Java version less than 8

Comment: Hopefully nobody. Java 7 is no more supported sice more than 5 years

Comment: Yes, hopefully, but if you were, would you not like to find a solution that can also help you?

Comment: I think you confuse `DateFormat` with `DateTimeFormatter`. `LocalDate.parse` accepts the latter.

Comment: @Jens - plenty of systems are still running with Java versions prior to 8. While it may not be supported by Oracle/Sun anymore, it still has to be supported by developers who come to StackOverflow looking for help.